# Linking GLEW fail

Tags: c++, static-linking, glew

I am trying to link GLEW to my project. I am using CodeBlocks, linker and compiler paths are properly set. In my library, there are two files (glew32.lib & glew32s.lib). When I tried to link `-lglew32s`, my linker complained:

```
ld.exe||cannot find -lglew32s|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

What could possibly be a problem here? When I changed `-lglew32s` to `-lglew32`, I got other type of errors (undefined references) that are related to dynamic linking, so I know my path is set properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably build GLEW from source to get `lib<name>.a` import libraries.  My recommendation is to grab the source from [here](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew) and build it with [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/).  You might be able to find some tutorials on Google if you need more specific instructions.

However, I've been told by sschuberth in the comments that this could be compatible, which makes sense because one of your libraries worked.  If you're sure both of these libraries exist in a path the linker knows about, I don't know exactly why this would happen.  Either it's an incorrect commend line, or you don't really have all of your libraries where you say you do.  Please show your command line for gcc and the files in the GLEW folder so I can better understand your situation.

Comment: While basically correct (see [Interoperability of Libraries Created by Different Compiler Brands](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands)), I'd expect another error message than `cannot find -lglew32s` in that case.

Comment: @sschuberth The error happened because he downloaded the Windows files and tried to link to the MinGW files, which didn't exist.

Comment: I'm not convinced about that. As [this page](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use) describes, when specifying `-l<name>`, MinGW / GCC will look for `<name>.lib` *in addition to* `lib<name>.a`.

Comment: @sschuberth Wow, I didn't know that.  I have always used MinGW with `lib<name>.a`, and didn't know it worked the other way.  I guess it might be possible to use those libraries interchangeably.